# How to include entity component in home page

Tags: angular, jhipster

I'm trying to show an entity page (generated by JHipster) in home page, like this:

```
<div class="container>
   Hello World
</div>

<jhi-boats></jhi-boats>
```

Turns out, only list of boats shows but not `"Hello World"`. I realized that, if I remove `jhi-boats` but the import of `BoatModule` remains in `home.module.ts`, the result is the same even though I removed `jhi-boats` tags from html. How to make "Hello World" and list of boats displayed in the same page, could it be an issue with the router?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12648#issuecomment-723209780

Basically, since modules are eagerly loaded, routes gets overwritten by the other. As I am loading BoatModule from HomeModule, routes from HomeModule gets overwritten.

Solution is to use lazy modules, more details here: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#lazy-loading-feature-modules

I created a HomeRoutingModule:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'boat',
    loadChildren: () => import('../entities/boat/boat.module').then(m => m.BoatModule)
  },
  HOME_ROUTE
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class HomeRoutingModule {}
```

And import it in HomeModule:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [SharedModule, HomeRoutingModule, BoatModule],
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

Home routes are no longer eagerly loaded, therefore no longer gets overwritten. Tiny detail, to load up the list I had to add `defaultSort` property to the route so my list of boats gets properly loaded (otherwise crash in `BoatComponent#fillComponentAttributeFromRoute`):

```
export const HOME_ROUTE: Route = {
  path: '',
  component: HomeComponent,
  data: {
    defaultSort: 'id,' + ASC,
    pageTitle: 'home.title',
  },
};
```